# Mojave upgrade complete, but warning that Server is out of date?

Tags: mojave

I received a OS X "Server" update from the store a few days ago.  Something about prepping for Mojave.  I've now done the Mojave update too.  Every boot I get a big warning box about my version of Server not being supported anymore.  Nothing new in the store so far.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the version of server app installed on your Mac?

Comment: It says October 16th, 2015.  However, I did let the Server update for Mojave install.  I'm confused.

Comment: Mac App Store shows the current version to be 5.6.3 which was released a week ago. Use this link: https://itunes.apple.com/app/macos-server/id883878097 to see what you get.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Oddly when I open that link and go to the store it shows Version 5.6.3, and it says I have it.  When I try to do an Open on it I get the "no longer supported" popup again...

Comment: I got another Server app update from Apple this morning.  Must have been an Apple bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to have been some kind of bug.  Later on received an app update that fixed the issue.